# Test coverage improvement

Tags: trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

I have written a trigger on Email message object and a test class, where its code coverage is not even 1%, please suggest me the best way - if am wrong.

Trigger :

```
trigger CloneClosedCase on EmailMessage (after insert) {
    Set<ID> caseSet = new Set<ID>();
    List<Case>cloneList = new List<Case>();
    Map<Id, String> emailBodyMap = new Map<Id, String>();

    for (EmailMessage so : Trigger.new) {
        //if(so.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.sObjectType && so.Incoming){
        if(((String)so.parentid).startsWith('500') && so.Incoming){
            caseSet.add(so.parentid);
            emailBodyMap.put(so.ParentId, so.TextBody);
        } 
    }

    Map<Id,case> caseMAP = new Map<Id,case>([SELECT id,origin,subject,Policy__c,Type,Claim__c,(select OldValue, NewValue from Histories),Complainant__c,SR_Sub_Type__c,Remarks_for_pending_status__c,status,description,parentid FROM Case WHERE id in:caseSet]);  
    Map<String,Group> groupMap = new Map<String,Group>();
    List<Group> allGroups = new List<Group>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Group]);

    for(Group g : allGroups){
        groupMap.put(g.DeveloperName,g);
    }

    for(Case c:caseMAP.values()){
        if(c.Status=='Closed' ||c.Status=='Pending CC' || c.Status=='Pending other department' ) {
            Case cloneCase = c.clone(false,true);
            cloneCase.parentid=c.id;
            if(cloneCase.Origin=='Email - Complaints'){
                cloneCase.Ownerid=groupMap.get('Inbound_Complaints').id;
            } else if(cloneCase.Origin=='Email - Claims'){
                cloneCase.Ownerid=groupMap.get('Inbound_Claims').id;
            } else if(cloneCase.Origin=='Email - Customer Service'){
                cloneCase.Ownerid=groupMap.get('Inbound_Customer_Service').id;
            }        
            else{
                cloneCase.Ownerid=groupMap.get('Inbound_Policy_Renewal').id;
            }

            cloneCase.Origin=c.Origin;
            //cloneCase.subject=c.subject;
            cloneCase.Policy__c=c.Policy__c;
            cloneCase.Claim__c=c.Claim__c;
            cloneCase.Type=c.Type;
            //cloneCase.SLA__c=c.SLA__c;
            //cloneCase.TAT_Due_Date__c=c.TAT_Due_Date__c;
            cloneCase.SR_Sub_Type__c=c.SR_Sub_Type__c;
            cloneCase.Status='New';
            cloneCase.Description= 'Child Subject :' + emailBodyMap.get(c.Id);
            cloneList.add(cloneCase);
            system.debug('*********************' +cloneList);
        }
    }

    try { 
        insert cloneList;      
    } catch(DMLException e) {   
        System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
private class CloneClosedCase_Test{
    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {  
        DmlException expectedException;
        Account acc = new Account(name = 'test'); 
        Insert acc;
        contact con = new contact(lastname ='testing', firstname = 'testcontact',email='testingit@gmail.com', accountid = acc.Id);
        Insert con;   
        Case c = new Case(Account = acc, Contact = con,Complainant__c = 'Self',  Origin = 'Email - Claims', Subject = 'Unit Test', Type = 'New Business', Status = 'Closed', SR_Sub_Type__c = 'Application Status', Description = 'Testing' );
        insert c;
        EmailMessage[] newEmail = new EmailMessage[0];
        newEmail.add(new EmailMessage(FromAddress = 'someone@somewhere.com', Incoming = True, ToAddress= 'someone@salesforce.com', Subject = 'Test email', TextBody = 'Test', ParentId = c.Id,Status = 'New')); 

        Test.startTest();  
        try{
            insert newEmail;
        } catch (DmlException d){
            expectedException = d;
        }
        Test.stopTest(); 

        system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException, 'A validation should occur');        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you remove @isTest(seealldata=true) and check any exception is occuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below two things : -

1. Wrap your testmethod `Messaging.sendEmail` method in a `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` method.  When the `stoptest()` is invoked, SFDC executes all async operations (e.g. sends the email).  Then do your asserts
2. If #1 doesn't work, write your testmethod to simulate the act of sending the email by doing an insert on `EmailMessage` as test data, then do database SOQL on the result of the trigger to see if the right stuff happened.